# Can I call HTML5 Functions from C#? Specifically for geolocation?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, console-application

The navigator.getCurrentLocation() js function is really useful.  But I have a basic console application written in c# .net and I want to use something similar.

Is there a c# lib or dll that mimics the functionality? Or some way to call that js function?

I'm not sure what's under the hood but it works much better than the classic IP location.

Comment: If you are using a WebApp you would be able to store the javascript value on your server via Ajax. I doubt there is a way to do this specifically with the HTML5 function using a Console Application though.

Comment: Without creating a webapp; the answer would be no. Maybe there are some third party c# libs out there to do such stuff but js methods; nope

Comment: So the scenario is a user is running a C# Console App on his/her desktop, and you want to get the location of that user?